# Apply CALayer mask to N views underneath?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, calayer

Wondering wether it possible to apply Mask of one CALayer to some number of views underneath it? For example, I want to place mask (representing a "hole") in `UITableViewCell` and apply its effect to `UITableView's` background so that I can see part of lowest view while dragging `UITableViewCell`